# Problems including header file from different directory [not a path issue]

Tags: c++, c, java-native-interface, header-files

I've long forgotten c++ and how to use it properly, but now I have to deal with one class and I'm a little bit stuck.
So I'm using cocos2dx to write a game for ios, however I am using Lua bindings instead of c++.
But... even though, I need to write something that uses JNI so... c/c++ here we come.

I've got the header file and cpp file like this:

DeviceInfoAndroid.h:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "../libs/cocos2dx/platform/android/jni/JniHelper.h"

extern "C" {

    const char* getAndroidDeviceId();

}
```

DeviceInfoAndroid.cpp:

```
#ifndef _DEVICE_INFO_ANDROID_
#define _DEVICE_INFO_ANDROID_

#include "DeviceInfoAndroid.h"
#include <string>

extern "C" {

const char *getAndroidDeviceId() {
    JniMethodInfo t;
    const char* retVal;
    if (JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(t
            , "org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxActivity" //org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxActivity
            , "getIMEI"
            , "()Ljava/lang/String;")) {
        jstring jstr;
        jstr = (jstring);
        t.env->CallStaticObjectMethod(t.classID, t.methodID);
        char *cstr;
        cstr = (char *) t.env->GetStringUTFChars(jstr, 0);
        std::string ret(cstr);
        t.env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstr, cstr);
        t.env->DeleteLocalRef(jstr);
        retVal = ret.c_str();
    }
    return retVal;
}
}

#endif
```

I know that all this #ifndef crap is not needed, since I only use this in one place and one place only so no cycle dependencies could occur, but I've added it anyway [it doesn't change when I remove it].

So.. path to the JniHelper.h file is correct. It looks like this btw.:

JniHelper.h

```
#ifndef __ANDROID_JNI_HELPER_H__
#define __ANDROID_JNI_HELPER_H__

#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include "CCPlatformMacros.h"

namespace cocos2d {

    typedef struct JniMethodInfo_
    {
        JNIEnv *    env;
        jclass      classID;
        jmethodID   methodID;
    } JniMethodInfo;

    class CC_DLL JniHelper
    {
    public:
        static JavaVM* getJavaVM();
        static void setJavaVM(JavaVM *javaVM);
        static jclass getClassID(const char *className, JNIEnv *env=0);
        static bool getStaticMethodInfo(JniMethodInfo &methodinfo, const char *className, const char *methodName, const char *paramCode);
        static bool getMethodInfo(JniMethodInfo &methodinfo, const char *className, const char *methodName, const char *paramCode);
        static std::string jstring2string(jstring str);

    private:
        static JavaVM *m_psJavaVM;
    };
}

#endif // __ANDROID_JNI_HELPER_H__
```

Okay.. now.. I use a makefile to build it [it's a part of a larger build process, but for this particular file it looks like this (it is located in the same directory as the .h and .cpp files I pasted here].

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := game_logic

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
AppDelegate.cpp \
DeviceInfoAndroid.cpp \
DeviceInfo.cpp \
../libs/lua/cocos2dx_support/LuaEngineImpl.cpp \
../libs/lua/cocos2dx_support/Cocos2dxLuaLoader.cpp \
../libs/lua/cocos2dx_support/LuaCocos2d.cpp \
../libs/lua/cocos2dx_support/LuaEngine.cpp \
../libs/lua/CocosDenshion_support/LuaSimpleAudioEngine.cpp \
../libs/lua/exts/luallthread/llthreads.c \
../libs/lua/exts/luasocket/auxiliar.c \
../libs/lua/exts/luasocket/buffer.c \
../libs/lua/exts/luasocket/except.c \
../libs/lua/exts/luasocket/inet.c \
../libs/lua/exts/luasocket/io.c \
../libs/lua/exts/luasocket/luasocket.c \
../libs/lua/exts/luasocket/mime.c \
../libs/lua/exts/luasocket/options.c \
../libs/lua/exts/luasocket/select.c \
../libs/lua/exts/luasocket/tcp.c \
../libs/lua/exts/luasocket/timeout.c \
../libs/lua/exts/luasocket/udp.c \
../libs/lua/exts/luasocket/unix.c \
../libs/lua/exts/luasocket/usocket.c \
../libs/lua/exts/lualoadexts.c \
../libs/lua/exts/luasocketscripts.c 

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/cocos2dx \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/cocos2dx/platform \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/cocos2dx/include \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/cocos2dx/lua_support \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/CocosDenshion/include \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/lua/lua \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/lua/tolua \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/lua/cocos2dx_support \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/lua/CocosDenshion_support \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/lua/exts \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/lua/exts/luallthread \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/lua/exts/luasocket \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/cocos2x/platform/android/jni \

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(call host-path, $(LOCAL_PATH)/../Android/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)) \
        -L$(call host-path, $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/libraries/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)) -lcurl \
        -lcocos2d \
        -lcocosdenshion \
        -llua

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

As you can see I've added the path to the JniHelper.h file to the LOCAL_C_INCLUDES.
I've tried removing the path and just using "JniHelper.h" but it throws an error saying that file does not exist.

The error I get during build is:

```
Compile++ thumb  : game_logic <= DeviceInfoAndroid.cpp
jni/../../Classes/DeviceInfoAndroid.cpp: In function 'const char* getAndroidDeviceId()':
jni/../../Classes/DeviceInfoAndroid.cpp:10: error: 'JniMethodInfo' was not declared in this scope
jni/../../Classes/DeviceInfoAndroid.cpp:10: error: expected ';' before 't'
jni/../../Classes/DeviceInfoAndroid.cpp:12: error: 'JniHelper' has not been declared
jni/../../Classes/DeviceInfoAndroid.cpp:12: error: 't' was not declared in this scope
jni/../../Classes/DeviceInfoAndroid.cpp:17: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/game_logic/DeviceInfoAndroid.o] Error 1
```

Any tips?
What have I done wrong?
I know that in order to write in C++ I have a lot to learn, but as I mentioned... I'm not going to write in C++, it's just a few lines of code I need to create for every device type I have to support in my game. I'm already done with objective-c and c++ mixing to get iOS device id.

EDIT:
when removing some comments of mine I've managed to remove include of DeviceInfoAndroid.cpp. I've corrected the code above. Sorry about that.

Comment: I updated my answer according to your changes. See below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**After your edit, here's my updated answer:**

JniMethodInfo exists in the namespace cocos2d, so you should reference to it as:

`cocos2d::JniMethodInfo t;`

Same goes for JniHelper:

`if (cocos2d::JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo`
etc.

**Answer before your edits: (not relevant anymore, but saved here for reference)**

You need to move the includes from the header file to the cpp file. DeviceInfoAndroid.h is not automatically included in DeviceInfoAndroid.cpp. You must include it manually.

Comment: I've corrected pasted code. Made a mistake when removing some comments

Comment: thanks a lot! Thanks for investigating and spending time with this issue of mine. I've added "using namespace cocos2d;" to the top of the file and now it compiles fine :) Thanks!